# Gaussian Elimination without pivot

Tags: calculus, matrices, numerical-methods, gaussian-elimination

[click here for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVL9p.png)

I understand Gaussian elim and the inverse, but am new to Gaussian elim without pivot. Wordiness of the question is also throwing me off. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to find $(I-A)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yeah not sure how to do it without pivot

Comment: First of all, you need to find $B=I-A$. Then, anything you do for finally calculating by GE should also be applied to $I$, then after all steps, you applied to $I$ you will find a matrix that is $(I-A)_{-1}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: If you need a comprehensive answer, include matrix $A$ in your question here.

Comment: I don’t understand how to get matrix A, I think after I get the matrix I should be okay

Answer (score 1):

Judging from how the question is worded, they seem to ask us not to use a permutation matrix, which in a literal sense means "pivoting" a matrix.

So solving with an A = LU Factorization should suffice. Which would involve working out E = I - A and then finding the inverse, as opposed to the more complete form PA = LU.

There wouldn't be a Gaussian Elimination without pivots, back substitution works on the fundamental idea of having pivots.

I hope that helps.

EDIT:

http://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104019/numerical-analysis/kadalbajoo/lec1/fnode5.html

Here is a small link depicting all three:

1. No Pivoting.
2. Partial Pivoting.
3. Fully Pivoting.

Comment: In the last section of the image, it clearly states gaussian elimination without pivoting.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Yes, just like I am saying "pivoting" a matrix in a more literal way means exchanging rows. The question doesn't want us to "pivot" a matrix partially or fully. "Pivot elements" are called so because of those operations. We commonly refer to them as "pivots" but because of the operations required to find them.

Comment: "There wouldn't be a Gaussian Elimination without pivots", that's not true if no diagonal elements are zero in solving steps for the division. You do not need to guess whether pivoting is needed or not when the question clearly states use GE without pivoting unless the question is wrong but it is not.

Comment: I know what pivoting is! You can see here some GE method examples that are solved without pivoting. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination